# perl vim {} cursor position on expanding

Tags: perl, vim

I have it in vim using delimitmate that the brackets autocomplete.

When using it for {} it correctly produces

```
{|}
```

when you press enter it takes you too

```
{
|}
```

Is there anyway to get it to expand ready to type so that its like this when using braces. So that enter expands it to this normally?

```
{
    |
}
```

Comment: Please read the documentation. You can use [`delimitMate_expand_cr`](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate/blob/543be33b13756eabc02cd91ef141c1d3fb216446/doc/delimitMate.txt#L370) for this. And if it worked for you, don't forget to post it as an answer below.

Comment: @gits           maybe I misunderstand the doc but <CR><CR><Up> is the solution in that documentation. So press enter twice and then the up key. That's what I am doing and trying to get working properly.

Comment: oh I think you meant something like this.       nnoremap <expr><CR> :call delimitMate_expand_cr<cr>

Comment: Yes you are misunderstanding: `<CR><CR><Up>` is what you would do normally  and `<CR>` is what you do with Delimitmate if you `let` that option.

Comment: @romainl        I was trying to use mapping found this let b:delimitMate_expand_cr = temp_varsDM[1] here http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/kronn/dotfiles/.vim/plugin/delimitMate.vim

Answer (score 1):

create `~/.vimrc` and put below lines in it:

```
" autoindent
autocmd FileType perl set autoindent|set smartindent
autocmd FileType python set autoindent|set smartindent

" 4 space tabs
autocmd FileType perl set tabstop=4|set shiftwidth=4|set expandtab|set softtabstop=4
autocmd FileType python set tabstop=4|set shiftwidth=4|set expandtab|set softtabstop=4

" show matching brackets
autocmd FileType perl set showmatch

" check perl code with :make
autocmd FileType perl set makeprg=perl\ -c\ %\ $*
autocmd FileType perl set errorformat=%f:%l:%m
autocmd FileType perl set autowrite
```

This works with .pl and .py files.

Type "{", press "enter", it will move to the next line after 4 spaces. continue writing your code. When done, press "enter" to go to the new line and type "}" and then press "enter", it will properly indent the closing curly bracket.

If this does not solve your problem then at-least this gives you a hint on how you can accomplish it by googling further on `~/.vimrc`

Answer (score 1):

I don't use that plugin, if it didn't provide you configuration, you can try this mapping for your filetype. assume you have autoindent:

```
inoremap <expr><CR> getline('.')[getpos('.')[2]:] == "}"?"<CR>":"<CR><ESC>O"
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for delimitMate

```
let g:delimitMate_expand_cr = '<CR>'
```

Actually the correct version is

```
let delimitMate_expand_cr = 1
au FileType mail let b:delimitMate_expand_cr = 1
```